# Почему выводится только последнее событие?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Как сделать, чтобы из базы выводилось не одно последнее событие, как сейчас, а последние три?

```html
<?php  
class exblastobmen_Widget2 extends WP_Widget {
  
  public function __construct($id_base = false, $widget_options = array(), $control_options = array()){
    parent::__construct('exblastobmen_info', __('The last exchange','pntheme'), $widget_options = array(), $control_options = array());
  }
  
  public function widget($args, $instance){
    extract($args);


    $title = ($instance['title'] !== null && $instance['title'] != '')? $instance['title'] : __('The last exchange','pntheme'); 
  
    $temp = '
    <div class="lobmen_widget">
        <div class="lobmenwidget_title">'. pn_strip_input($title) .'</div>'; 
  
      global $wpdb;
    $valuts = array();
    $valutsn = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."valuts");
    foreach($valutsn as $valut){
      $valuts[$valut->id] = $valut;
    } 
    $bid = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bids WHERE status = 'success' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");     
    if(isset($bid->id)){
      

      if(isset($valuts[$bid->valut1i]) and isset($valuts[$bid->valut2i])){
            
        $table ='
        <div class="lobmentable">
          <div class="lobmline">
            <div class="lobmlineico">
              <div class="obmenlinewico" style="background: url('. is_ssl_url($valuts[$bid->valut1i]->vlogo) .') no-repeat center center"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="lobmlinebac">
              '. exb_is_my_rez($bid->summ1) .'&nbsp;'. pn_strip_input($bid->valut1type) .'
            </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
              
          <div class="lobmlinepr"></div>
              
          <div class="lobmline">
            <div class="lobmlineico">
              <div class="obmenlinewico" style="background: url('. is_ssl_url($valuts[$bid->valut2i]->vlogo) .') no-repeat center center"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="lobmlinebac">
              '. exb_is_my_rez($bid->summz2) .'&nbsp;'. pn_strip_input($bid->valut2type) .'
            </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
          </div> 
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        ';
        $temp .= $table;
          
      } 
      
      
        
      if(isset($bid->tdate)){
        $temp .= '<div class="lobmendate">'. get_mytime($bid->tdate, 'd.m.Y H:i') .'</div>';
      }
    }
    
    
        $temp .= '
    </div>
    ';  
      echo $temp; 
  }
  
  public function form($instance){ 
  ?>
  <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title'); ?>: </label><br />
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" id="<?php $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" class="widefat" value="<?php echo is_isset($instance,'title'); ?>">
  </p>
  <?php
  } 
  
}

register_widget('exblastobmen_Widget2');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем SQL запросе стоит ORDER BY id DESC **LIMIT 1**. Поставьте LIMIT 3 и тогда будут выводиться последние 3 записи! Пробегитесь по ним циклом и выводите!